# How do i get values from a post form and use them in the rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My controller needs to use the values from the form to get user and start a session.

the values do not seem to be posted , the session is never started, the else statement always seems to be executed rather than the if which needs to be executed.

**controller**

```
def new
    end

def create
    uid = params[:uid]
    role = params[:role]

    user=User.find_by(userid:uid,role:role)
    if user 

        session[ :user_id]=user.id
        redirect_to controller: 'stuff', action: 'index'
    else
        render 'new', alert:
          "err"
        end
end
```

**new.html.erb VIEW**

```
<h1 class ="card-header"> Log IN </h1>

            <%= form_for :session, url: sessions_path do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :uid %>
                <%= f.text_field :uid %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :role %>
                <%= f.text_field :password %>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
                <%= submit_tag 'Log In' %>                
            </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
```

**routes**

```
resources :sessions
```

Comment: please post your rails server logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your uid and role parameter will be available inside a symbol called session

so the params will look like this

```rb
params: {
# other  symbols
  session: {
     uid: // your uid,
     role: // your role
  }
}
```

so when you access the uid and role like this

```rb
uid = params[:uid]
role = params[:role]
```

it will be nil since they are stored inside the session s symbol.

so the correct way to access them is like this

```rb
def create
    uid = params[:session][:uid]
    role = params[:session][:role]

    user=User.find_by(userid:uid,role:role)
    if user 

        session[ :user_id]=user.id
        redirect_to controller: 'stuff', action: 'index'
    else
        render 'new', alert:
          "err"
        end
end
```

Comment: @Coder1234 glad i was of help, no need :)